# Multiple Countdown with timezone

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I need to use Multiple Countdown in a single page with timezone.. I found [Final Countdown](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/examples/multiple-instances.html)

I found the code i needed. but couldnt get it to work in the right timezone.

```
    $(function(){
 $('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
   $this.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {
     $this.html(event.strftime('%H:%M:%S'));
   });
 });
});
```

This is for the multiple countdowns which works fine..

This one is for timezone with a single countdown.

```
var nextYear = moment.tz("2020-05-29 00:00", "America/Sao_Paulo");

$('#clock').countdown(nextYear.toDate(), function(event) {
  $(this).html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
});
```

How can i get the first one work with proper timezone..
thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the moment timezone function to pass the date with timezone to each countdown.

This is what you are looking for?

```
$(function(){
    $('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
        $this.countdown(moment.tz(finalDate, "America/Sao_Paulo").toDate(), function(event) {
            $this.html(event.strftime('%H:%M:%S'));
        });
    });
});
```

To get the user local timezone you can try

```
console.log(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone); // America/Sao_Paulo
//or with moment
console.log(moment.tz.guess()) // America/Sao_Paulo
```

Make sure you import moment cdn libraries

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.31/moment-timezone.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.31/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```